# Compiling markdown at run-time in a Svelte component using mdsvex

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm trying to take a string containing markdown in a Svelte template and use that as part of a Svelte component using [mdsvex](https://mdsvex.pngwn.io/docs/) I have the following code in **App.svelte**:

```
<script>
  import { compile } from 'mdsvex';
  import Counter from './lib/Counter.svelte'

  const transformed_code = compile(`
    # Hello world

    This is a paragraph

    <Counter />
  `, {});

</script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Once that's done, I want to add the result inside the `#content` box. When I run the compile step, I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined

What exactly am I doing wrong? And is this actually possible to do using mdsvex? Thanks for any help?

Answer (score 3):

The module is intended to be used on the server and uses the Node variable `process`. The [playground page](https://mdsvex.pngwn.io/playground) shims the variable based on this: https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-process/blob/master/browser.js

You can define a `process` object like that and assign it on the window. Make sure that this code runs on the client:

```js
window.process = { /* fake process here */ }
```

Once this is done, the code will execute, but the `Counter` will not work like this; the import does nothing. The output of `mdsvex` has to be compiled with Svelte, which generates code that tries to access an undefined `Counter` component.

There are multiple possible approaches:

- Somehow inject the imported component constructor, e.g. via a prop (though I have run into errors because of an unset `target` option)
- Precompile any component you want to use like this and make them available as a route that can imported from the compiled output
- Compile the component on the fly. You will need to have some way to get the component source code for processing

If you have nested component imports, option 2 is probably the most viable, since you then can adjust all import URLs at the time you generate the compiled output.